# Fabric.js creating temporary canvas for subclass

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

I'm trying to subclass the Text class in fabric.js and create a temporary canvas which I want the Text class to render onto then manipulate before rendering onto the final context provided by the _render function.

The problem I'm running into is that the temporary canvas is not rendering correctly (Text._render() is rendering correctly on the temporary canvas). I've run into various issues (some of which I have resolved) such as the origin being the center of the image but a lack of understanding about what the context supplied to _render has as a scale and dimensions and canvas contexts lack of transparency have caught me. One issue is caused by using a MacBook pro with retina support.

I've supplied a fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/qxbwjpg2/2/

How can I alter this fiddle to the extent that the Text class will render onto a temporary canvas that I can then use drawImage onto my own classes _render context to produce the correct output on my fabric canvas? From there I should be able to modify the temporary canvas before copying into the final canvas.

You can see that it partially works but the rendered text is in the wrong place and scaling is totally broken.

There are two issues I see:

```
this.callSuper('_render', octx);
```

Does not increase the resolution as the text object is scaled on the fabric.js canvas

```
//this is where it really happens - octx is where the text was written to by original text function
_drawTextEffect: function(octx, ctx) {
  var left = -(octx.width /2) ;
  var top = -(octx.height/2);

  //for now just draw!!
  ctx.drawImage(octx, left ,top,octx.width, octx.height );

},
```

Just copying one context to another does not work.

Comment: I can fix the positioning properly by calling ctx.resetTransform() before drawing the temporary canvas at 0,0 rather than trying to work out a negative position.

The only issue remaining is that when I scale the object it keeps getting rendered on the temporary canvas at the original size. If I just render the super class directly onto the ctx provided it does scale properly. This has me trumped as I cannot even begin to rationalise why it happens.